# Avoid Warning after Android 7 Update for nonDaydream devices?

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

after the the long awaitet Android 7 update my S7 shows [Android 7 Google VR services - Warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWucD.png) dialog everytime the VrView (https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/widgets/video/VrVideoView) is rendered...

Im quite sure that this behaviour is related to this:

> "...N+ devices, if Google VR Services is not present and enabled, this
>   will prompt the user to install or enable Google VR Services before
>   continuing..."
>   Taken from AndroidCompat NDK reference /vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/ndk/base/AndroidCompat

Is there any chance to avoid this kind of "issue" because the S7 did not support the Google VR services app - so this warning will pop up every time!

Any ideas?

BR

Answer (score 0):

I have just dealed with this problem. In unity, there's an "AndroidDevice" Class which will use google vr services In googlevr sdk.

This class is in AndroidDevice.cs,  just annotate the code related with ActivityListenerClass will be ok.

Comment: Its a native Android project - unity code wont help =|

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in my app, where I used PanoramaVrView only. 
I had 2 dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.40.0'
compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.40.0'
```

and this line in my activity class

```
AndroidCompat.setVrModeEnabled(activity, true)
```

I just removed base dependency

```
compile 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.40.0'
```

and this

```
AndroidCompat.setVrModeEnabled(activity, true)
```

line from my activity, and warning doesn't appear anymore.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/AndroidCompat.html#setVrModeEnabled(Activity,boolean)